# Use linux version of a command instead of the BSD version

Tags: columns, bsd, pop-os

I have a utility bash script from an old laptop that I'm trying to use on my current laptop. It fails because it's passing unknown options to the `column` command. Running `man column`, I see that this machine is using [the BSD version](https://man.openbsd.org/column.1) of the command; the script is written for [the Linux version](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html), which has more options.

I don't have access to the old machine, so I can't say much about what might have been done to set it up, except that it should be *very similar* to the new one. The current machine is running Pop!OS 20.04, newly installed in the last couple days.

Is there an obviously correct way to specify which of these similar commands I want to use?

Comment: This turns out to be a deeply frustrating problem. The relationships between the different repo/distro managers are snarled; they _know_ they're shipping the wrong version of the command, but nobody's taking bets on when the issue will get fixed (this is hardly a mainstream problem, and nobody want's to break anything that's currently working). [This ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098248/how-can-i-install-the-util-linux-version-of-the-column-command-in-18-04) has working solutions for my current problem, and links for people who want to dig into the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an obviously correct way to specify which of these similar
> commands I want to use?

At the risk of being a little *too* obvious, one obvious way is to specify the full path to the exact executable you want the script to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# use the col executable in /usr/bin, not that other one:
col='/usr/bin/col'

$col ... ... ...
```

As @muru points out, an alternative would be to declare a function `col()` which calls the specific binary that you wish to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# use the col executable in /usr/bin, not that other one:
col()
{
  /usr/bin/col "$@"
}

col ... ... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Find them all with, e.g. `type -a column`, rearrange your `$PATH` so that the directory containing the version you want is before the directory containing the version you don't want. Then, issue the `rehash` command.

`PATH` editing is tricky. Never have a `PATH=` assignment that doesn't have `$PATH` in it, unless you're really sure what you're doing.

I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz